# Jackson: Generate property to json field name mapping

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a requirement where I need to print / generate the full mapping of properties to the corresponding fields. To make myself clear, I am posting a snippet of the sample code, along with the output I expect.

```
public class A{
   @JsonProperty("aJsonField")
   private String a;
   @JsonProperty("bJsonField")
   private String b;
   @JsonProperty("cJsonField")
   private String c;
   @JsonProperty("dJsonField")
   private D d;
   @JsonProperty("fJsonField")
   private List<Integer> f;
   @JsonProperty("gJsonField")
   private List<G> g;
 // Corresponding getters and setters follow (Not shown)... 
}

public class D{
   @JsonProperty("eJsonField")
   private String e;
}

public class G{
   @JsonProperty("kJsonField")
   private String k;
}
```

Output: When run on class A, this should be the output:

```
a -> aJsonField
b -> bJsonField
c -> cJsonField
d.e -> dJsonField.eJsonField
f -> fJsonField
g.k -> gJsonField.kJsonField
```

Whereas, when run on class d, this should be the output:

```
e -> eJsonField
```

I could not find any reference in Jackson about any method that currently addresses my requirement. Please note that if there is a way to print the mapping in reverse (like `cJsonField -> c`, `dJsonField.eJsonField -> d.e` etc.), I can live with it. I am using Jackson v. 2.6.

I poured over this link [Jackson: generate schemas with references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149685/jackson-generate-schemas-with-references), but this does not address my requirement.

Thanks,

Anupam